# Async download using blocks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

The following code lies within `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

1.) i need to modify this code in a way i could, cancel the download or the block when the viewDissapears. I think, i should first initialize a block in the `.h` file, and then use it in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, then set it to nil when `viewDidDissapear`. (I am not sure if this approach is correct). Can someone please help me edit this code ?

note: What should hapen is, when the user is on a particular view, and when the following code is downloading some images, the user decides to move to another view. Then i want to cancel the download in the `viewDidDissapear` method

```
dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);    
    dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{        
        NSData *image = // I will be downloading an URL here            
        //this will set the image when loading is finished
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          // I will be displaying the Downloaded image here
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not wait for the view to disappear, and cancel the operation in the `prepareForReuse` method of your table view cell. Otherwise you may see a cell get recycled before the download finishes (e.g. because the user did a fast scroll), and then the finished download would show wrong content before the correct one overwrites it. Other than that, your approach looks workable.

Answer (score 0):

you should look here: 
http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2011/02/28/cocoa-touch-tutorial-using-grand-central-dispatch-for-asynchronous-table-view-cells/
that's definitely what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

Downloading is already asynchronous, so wrapping it with GCD just complicates matters. Here's a downloadable project that you can try, that downloads images in the background and adds them to a table view when they arrive. You can easily add code that cancels the download when a downloader object is released:

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-4-Book-Examples/blob/master/p754p772downloader/p754downloader/RootViewController.m

Comment: Is this using ASIHTTPRequest ?

Comment: I don't know what that is. Look at the code, you can see what it's using. It's a complete working project; all the code is there. No tricks.